# if I include "new Date().getTime()" in the name of a generated .xls file, the generated file will never be detected using fs.existsSync(pathImagen)

Tags: javascript

I am using a library called `excel4node` to generate .xlsx files, the library generates them well and places them in the folder that I specify. But this function for some reason does not detect the generated file. if I give my file a name for example:
    var nameExcel = `report.xlsx`

It is recognized by the function, but if I put a name to the style:

```
var nameExcel = `reporte${new Date().getMonth() + "" + new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`
```

it doesn't appear as if the file was created when using this function, but in the folder if it is generated:

```
    wb.write(`./reportes/${nameExcel}`);  //file always is generated
    let pathImagen = path.resolve(__dirname, `../reportes/${nameExcel}`);

    if (fs.existsSync(pathImagen)) {
        //var nameExcel = `report.xlsx`
        res.sendFile(pathImagen);
    } else {
     //var nameExcel = `reporte${new Date().getMonth() + "" + new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`
    }
```

why is this happening?

full code:

```
    app.get('/reporte_usuarios/:filtro', [verificaToken], function (req, res) {


        Usuario.find({}, (err, usuarioDB) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

                return res.status(200).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }


            var nameExcel = `reporte.xlsx`   ////// withouth error
            var nameExcel = `reporte${new Date().getMonth() + "" + new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`   ////// witherror

            var wb = new xl.Workbook();
            var ws = wb.addWorksheet("Hoja 1");
            var estiloHeaders = wb.createStyle(CONSTANTS.estilosExcel.headers);


            usuarioDB.forEach((usuario, i) => {
                ws.cell((2 + i), 1).string(usuario.nombres);
             .
             .
             .
            });

            wb.write(`./reportes/${nameExcel}`);
            let pathImagen = path.resolve(__dirname, `../reportes/${nameExcel}`);

            if (fs.existsSync(pathImagen)) {
                res.sendFile(pathImagen);
            } else {
                //            var nameExcel = `reporte${new Date().getMonth() + "" + new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`   ////// witherror

                return res.status(200).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: "No se ha podido generar el reporte"
                });
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: what is happing after else ??

Comment: cool, can you give a concrete example of what's in `nameExcel` after you run that assignment? Also note that the code you're showing is either too much because the file doesn't get created, or it's too much because it _does_ get created but your code refuses to read it in. In either case: can you remove the code that doesn't matter for the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @xdeepakv it simply says that the file does not exist.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated my code, thanks

Comment: @xdeepakv I update my code

Comment: I don't understand your updated code: it doesn't tell us anything new, _what's **in** the variable_? I.e. what is the _actual_ string it turns into? And does that _write_ the file to disk? If so, what's in the file? (if you check yourself, not "with node"). Is that valid content?